# WPF - How to get templated part in subclassed control (ComboBox)

Tags: wpf, combobox, subclass

We are trying to subclass a System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox in order to implement some custom editing behavior.
To do that, we need the EditableTextBox.
The class definition:

```
public class CustomComboBox : System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox
```

In the OnLoaded() handler, trying to find that part fails:

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        var cb = sender as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;
        Debug.Assert(cb != null);

        var textBox = cb.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", cb);
        Debug.Assert(textBox != null, "How is this possible -- TextBox not found?");
```

'textBox' is null after the call to FindName().
In the debugger, I find the name "PART_EditableTextBox" in cb.Template.ChildNames.
What are we doing wrong?
Thanks --

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve a part of a control in a derived class, you should use the [GetTemplateChild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.gettemplatechild?view=netframework-4.7.2) method. The right place to use this method is in the [OnApplyTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.onapplytemplate?view=netframework-4.7.2) override of your custom control, after the base method is called.

You can find a sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/creating-a-control-that-has-a-customizable-appearance) (take a look in the "*Anticipate Missing FrameworkElement Objects*" section) or [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179105/How-to-access-Control-Template-parts-from-Code-Beh).

Moreover your custom `ComboBox` must have its property `IsEditable` set to `true` (otherwise it will use a template without that part, you can take a look to `ComboBox` default style by using [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy)).

```
<local:CustomComboBox IsEditable="True">
```

So your code should be:

```
public class CustomComboBox : ComboBox
{
    private TextBox editableTextBox;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        if (IsEditable)
        {
            editableTextBox = GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox") as TextBox;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it can help you.